# redirect from subdomain to different host without 301

Tags: apache, dns, lamp

I need to point from `someSub.somedomain.com` to `mysub.mydomain.com`, and I need the url of the site to continue reading `someSub.somedomain.com`

I've tried many variations of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://DomainB.com/$1 [P]
```

But I can't seem to get anything to work. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This answer kind of already answers this question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/506623/masking-the-url-in-a-mod-rewrite

But it appears to me what you are looking for is a reverse proxy.

In the virtual host for your server:

```
    ServerName somesub.somedomain.com
    ProxyPass "/" http://mysub.mydomain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse "/" http://mysub.somedomain.com/
```

Now when you go to your http://somesub.somedomain.com all the requests will behind the scenes actually be going to http://mysub.mydomain.com but the browser user won't see that.

There are various customizations to this you can make.

Don't forget to enable `mod_proxy`

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the answer. So would this be a host configuration? Or would this work in a .htaccess file?

Comment: you put this in your httpd.conf